# How to hide the "Missing parameter" message

Tags: asp.net, web-services

In an asp.net web service (asmx), how do I hide the error messages that are sent to the client when it doesn't send the proper parameter: "Missing parameter: parameterName."?
In the web.config I have a custom error page setup that works in actual errors, but this doesn't appear to effect the web service parameter validation.

Thanks

Comment: The custom error page is for reporting errors to users, a web service is a system to system interface. I'm not clear as to why you'd want to suppress the interface error messages. Can you explain further, just in case there's a better approach to the issue.

Comment: Sure, it's a security concern because it gives information as to how one should work with the service. Those who need to work with the service got all info in advance and security personal don't want others to have an easy time figuring it out.